# C++ write an array to a binary entry in the registry

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I need to write an array into a BINARY registry key.

The array contains a series of characters...

char ArrayUserName[100]

it is loaded with the value of ZK8ORQ1

I need to write that value to a binary value (REG_BINARY) in the registry.

```
void WriteRegistryValues()
{
DWORD  dwDisposition;
FILE *fileb; 
fileb = fopen("C:\\logs\\cplog2.txt", "a+");

fprintf(fileb,"Field ID %d: [%s]\n", 2, ArrayUserName);
fprintf(fileb,"Field ID %d: [%s]\n", 3, ArrayPassword);

HKEY hKey;
LPCTSTR sk = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\XXXX\\YYYY\\GINA");
LONG openRes = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sk, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS , &hKey);


if (openRes==ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    fprintf(fileb, "Success opening key.\n");
} else {
    fprintf(fileb, "Error opening key.\n");
}

LPCTSTR value = TEXT("Domain");
LONG setRes = RegSetValueEx(hKey, value, 0, REG_BINARY, (CONST BYTE*)ArrayUserName, 100);


if (setRes == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    fprintf(fileb, "Success writing to Registry.\n");
} else {
    fprintf(fileb, "Error writing to Registry.\n");
}

LONG closeOut = RegCloseKey(hKey);

if (closeOut == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    fprintf(fileb, "Success closing key.\n");
} else {
    fprintf(fileb, "Error closing key.\n");
}

fclose(fileb);
```

In the text file, i see the values of the username and the password

as

Field ID 2: [zk8orq1]

Field ID 3: [P@ssword2]

Success opening key.

Error writing to Registry.

Success closing key.

What am i missing?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I can see is that you want to use `UCHAR byteRegArray`, instead of `char`,

```
 UCHAR byteRegArray[] = {0x01, 0x00....... };
 RegSetValueEx(hKey, "sflaksdfl;asjdf", 0, REG_BINARY, (BYTE *)byteRegArray, sizeof(byteRegArray));
```

you also need to check what the error message is, not just compare to ERROR_SUCCESS, I believe there are more specific ERROR code.

Comment: Very close....  thank you....   but it is writing the full 100 places to the registry.   I only used 8 or the 100...